# How to set proxy while using googletrans lib python

Tags: python, proxy, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using googletrans lib in python to translate my text. Can someone help me out how do we set proxies in goolgetrans object?

Version of googletrans :3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
Based on the error described in the comments, you show use the following code. Tested on my environment point to a proxy on cloud:

##### Whitout password:

```py
from googletrans import Translator
from httpcore import SyncHTTPProxy

proxy={"https": SyncHTTPProxy((b'http', b'<proxy server ip>', 3128, b''))}

# http = proxy protocol
# <proxy server ip> = proxy server ip / localhost if its local
# 3128 = proxy server port, change to yours


translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com'],proxies=proxy)
translation = translator.translate("Der Himmel ist blau und ich mag Bananen", dest='en')
print(translation.text)
```

##### With Password authentication:

```py
from googletrans import Translator
from httpcore import SyncHTTPProxy
from base64 import b64encode


def build_proxy_headers(username, password):
    userpass = (username.encode("utf-8"), password.encode("utf-8"))
    token = b64encode(b":".join(userpass))
    return [(b"Proxy-Authorization", b"Basic " + token)]


proxy_url=(b"http", b"<my_proxy_host_ip> ", 3128, b'')     # <my_proxy_host_ip> as `bytes`, <my_proxy_port> as `int`
proxy_headers = build_proxy_headers("<username>","<password>" )  # <my_username>, <my_password> as `str`
proxy={"https": SyncHTTPProxy(proxy_url=proxy_url, proxy_headers=proxy_headers) }

translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com'],proxies=proxy)
translation = translator.translate("Der Himmel ist blau und ich mag Bananen", dest='en')
print(translation.text)
```

---

##### Previous answer

The `googletrans` uses the `httpx` library, you can follow its documentation do configure the proxy connection:

send the proxy data in a dictionary variable:

```py
proxies_def = {
    "http://": "http://localhost:8030",
    "https://": "http://localhost:8031",
}

#Or with authentication:
proxies_def = {
    "http://": "http://username:password@localhost:8030",
    # ...
}
```

```py
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator(proxies=proxies_def)
```

Check the httpx documentation [here](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#http-proxying).

Comment: No. Its getting me an warning , Expected type 'Optional[Dict[str,SyncHTTPTransport]]',got 'Dict[str,str]' instead. I tried running it with warning but Connection timed out occurred

Comment: Hi @MandarRaut, I've revised the library, and depending on the version, it may change. Based on the error you have described, you have to add some additional code, I have edited the answer to reflect it. Please try it on you environment. I have created a proxy on gcp and executed the code on my local machine pointing to the proxy server and it worked as expected. I can see the connection passing throughout the proxy.

Comment: With this you should be able to use the proxy with both authenticated and non authenticated connections @MandarRaut